# Resolving dependencies in main thread vs. async tasks

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am developing an MVC-ish (possibly more like MVP) desktop application, using Unity, which has a main UI thread and periodically runs async tasks in the background.  The main window's UI events are handled by `MainController`.  When the user opens a new window, `MainController` will create a new child controller and pass in whatever dependencies it needs.  When a timer in the main window ticks, it calls a method on `MainController` which starts an async task.  There is task synchronization in `MainController` so I don't have more than one aysnc task running at a time.

I'm injecting two service facades and the async task scheduler into `MainController`.  The two service facades have one service which they each depend on.

The facade services and task scheduler service look like this:

```
public class FacadeOne : IFacadeOne
{
    private readonly IFirstService firstService;
    private readonly ISecondService secondService;

    public FacadeOne(IFirstService firstService, ISecondService secondService)
    {
       this.firstService = firstService;
       this.secondService = secondService;
    }
}

public class FacadeTwo : IFacadeTwo
{
    private readonly IFirstService firstService;
    private readonly IThirdService thirdService;

    public FacadeTwo(IFirstService firstService, IThirdService thirdService)
    {
       this.firstService = firstService;
       this.thirdService = thirdService;
    }
}    

public class TaskScheduler : ITaskScheduler
{
   private readonly IFacadeOne facadeOne;
   private readonly IFacadeTwo facadeTwo;

    public TaskScheduler(IFacadeOne facadeOne, IFacadeTwo facadeTwo)
    {
       this.facadeOne = facadeOne;
       this.facadeTwo = facadeTwo;
    }
}
```

`MainController` looks like this

```
public class MainController
{
   private readonly IFacadeOne facadeOne;
   private readonly IFacadeTwo facadeTwo;
   private readonly ITaskScheduler taskScheduler;

   public MainController(IFacadeOne facadeOne, IFacadeTwo facadeTwo, ITaskScheduler taskScheduler)
   {
      this.facadeOne = facadeOne;
      this.facadeTwo = facadeTwo;
      this.taskScheduler = taskScheduler;
   }
}
```

`FacadeOne` and `FacadeTwo` both have dependencies on `FirstService`.

In my composition root, I create an instance of `MainController`.  When I create that instance, I want the following to happen ([here is a diagram which hopefully makes it clearer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUt45.jpg)):

- The `facadeOne` and `facadeTwo` parameters of `MainController` should each use the same instance of `ServiceOne`.
- The `facadeOne` and `facadeTwo` parameters which are passed into the `taskScheduler` parameter when it is resolved should be different instances than the `facadeOne` and `facadeTwo` parameters which are passed into `MainController`'s constructor.
- When the `taskScheduler` parameter is resolved, its `facadeOne` and `facadeTwo` parameters should use the same instance of `FirstService` as each other, but it should be a different instance that the one used by `MainController`'s `facadeOne` and `facadeTwo` parameters.
- When the `taskScheduler` parameter is resolved, its `facadeOne` and `facadeTwo` parameters should use different instances of `SecondService` and `ThirdService` (and also `FirstService` as stated above) than those instances used by `MainController`'s `facadeOne` and `facadeTwo` parameters.

Is there an easy way to do this in Unity using lifetime managers, rather than creating a convoluted and error-prone sequence of `Resolve`s, `RegisterInstance`s, and temporary variables?

Comment: _"...best way..."_ is subject to opinion and sadly off-topic for SO. [ask]

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: I would rename the question something like "Resolving instances with a mix of TransientLifetimeManager and ContainerControlledLifetimeManager.", but since it's a drastic change, I'll let you do it if you feel like it!

Comment: As described in [this article](http://criticalsoftwareblog.com/index.php/2015/08/23/why-di-containers-fail-with-complex-object-graphs/), you are creating a "Complex object graph". DI containers don't work well in these cases. [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see <s>two</s> one ways of doing it, the second to be avoided!

**Named Registration with ContainerControlledLifetimeManager**

If you don't mind doubling some registration with named registrations, you can do that:

```
container.RegisterType<IFirstService, FirstService>("MainThread", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<ISecondService, SecondService>("MainThread", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IThirdService, ThirdService>("MainThread", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

container.RegisterType<IFirstService, FirstService>("TaskScheduler", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<ISecondService, SecondService>("TaskScheduler", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IThirdService, ThirdService>("TaskScheduler", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());


container.RegisterType<IFacadeOne, FacadeOne>("MainThread", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<IFirstService>("MainThread"),
        new ResolvedParameter<ISecondService>("MainThread")));

container.RegisterType<IFacadeTwo, FacadeTwo>("MainThread", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<IFirstService>("MainThread"),
        new ResolvedParameter<IThirdService>("MainThread")));

container.RegisterType<IFacadeOne, FacadeOne>("TaskScheduler", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<IFirstService>("TaskScheduler"),
        new ResolvedParameter<ISecondService>("TaskScheduler")));

container.RegisterType<IFacadeTwo, FacadeTwo>("TaskScheduler", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<IFirstService>("TaskScheduler"),
        new ResolvedParameter<IThirdService>("TaskScheduler")));

container.RegisterType<ITaskScheduler, TaskScheduler>("TaskScheduler", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<IFacadeOne>("TaskScheduler"),
        new ResolvedParameter<IFacadeTwo>("TaskScheduler")));

container.RegisterType<MainController>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<IFacadeOne>("MainThread"),
        new ResolvedParameter<IFacadeTwo>("MainThread"),
        new ResolvedParameter<ITaskScheduler>("TaskScheduler")));

MainController imWhatYouWanted = container.Resolve<MainController>();
```

Note1: You could remove all the "MainThread" names (not the registration, but simply make it *not-named-* and it would work the same. Same with the registration for `ITaskScheduler` itself, you could simply not name it, but you would still need to use names in it's `ResolvedParameters`.

Note2: You could use `HierarchicalLifetimeManager` instead of `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager`. They behave the same if you don't use child containers.

**Hack I don't recommend**

Another way you could do it, which I don't recommend unless you can absolutely not used named registrations, is to : use `HierarchicalLifetimeManager` instead of `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager`, combined with a child container:

```
container.RegisterType<IFirstService, FirstService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<ISecondService, SecondService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IThirdService, ThirdService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

container.RegisterType<IFacadeOne, FacadeOne>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<IFirstService>(),
        new ResolvedParameter<ISecondService>()));

container.RegisterType<IFacadeTwo, FacadeTwo>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<IFirstService>(),
        new ResolvedParameter<IThirdService>()));

IUnityContainer childContainer = container.CreateChildContainer();

childContainer.RegisterType<ITaskScheduler, TaskScheduler>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<IFacadeOne>(),
        new ResolvedParameter<IFacadeTwo>()));

// Resolve at registration time == Bad.
// You could do a work around too, but that's another lesson!
ITaskScheduler taskScheduler = childContainer.Resolve<ITaskScheduler>();

container.RegisterInstance<ITaskScheduler>(taskScheduler);

container.RegisterType<MainController>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<IFacadeOne>(),
        new ResolvedParameter<IFacadeTwo>(),
        new ResolvedParameter<ITaskScheduler>()));

MainController imWhatYouShouldntWant = container.Resolve<MainController>();
```

With that second solution, by using `HierarchicalLifetimeManager`, and having it resolved on the child container, *Unity* won't consider anything (with that LifetimeManager) when you resolve on the parent.

Note3: *Good job providing an image, it made it easy to understand what you wanted!*

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't know about using named instances.  Your suggestion is much better than the hacky way I was going to do it.  Thank you.

Comment: Always a pleasure!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your scenario and diagram it's clear what you actually want is to create a new child container from which to resolve the task scheduler. You can do this quite simply with a proxy class for `ITaskScheduler` that forwards calls to a `TaskScheduler` resolved from a child container.

First set up the parent container. Using the `HierarchicalLifetimeManager` will give us a new instance whenever we resolve in a child container:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IFirstService, FirstService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<ISecondService, SecondService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IThirdService, ThirdService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IFacadeOne, FacadeOne>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IFacadeTwo, FacadeTwo>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

// Note that we don't map this against ITaskScheduler
container.RegisterType<TaskScheduler>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

container.RegisterType<MainController>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Then we add the registration for the proxy TaskScheduler:

```
container.RegisterInstance<ITaskScheduler>(new UnityChildScopedTaskScheduler(container), new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Where `UnityChildScopedTaskScheduler` is declared as:

```
public class UnityChildScopedTaskScheduler : ITaskScheduler, IDisposable
{
    private IUnityContainer childContainer;

    private ITaskScheduler realTaskScheduler;
    private ITaskScheduler taskScheduler
    {
        get 
        {
            if(realTaskScheduler == null)
            {
                realTaskScheduler = childContainer.Resolve<TaskScheduler>();
            }

            return realTaskScheduler;
        }
    }

    public UnityChildScopedTaskScheduler(IUnityContainer container) 
    {
        childContainer = container.CreateChildContainer();
    }

    // Implement ITaskScheduler methods, passing the calls to taskScheduler

    public void Dispose() 
    {
        childContainer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Most the code should be self-explanatory. Simply pass in the parent container and resolve the real task scheduler when it is first used. You could obviously make this generic and apply to other classes. I think you can also have the container inject itself but I prefer injecting it directly so it's more obvious what's going on!

Finally resolve your controller from the main container as usual and you're good to go:

```
var controller = container.Resolve<MainController>();
```

[Here's a dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CDG0Ve) which shows the object hash codes.